# How the event is propagated?

Tags: qt, events, event-handling, event-propagation

I have a main window. It has a central widget and a docked tree widget. Right click a tree item, a context menu pops up. Right click somewhere in the tree but out of the menu, a mouse event is generated. How does the mouse event propagate? Begin from the menu? And then ...?

Comment: What happened to your debugger and your debug build of Qt? :)

Answer (score 1):

If the mouse button is pressed, the tree widget will get the event, regardless of whether a context menu is open or not.

Comment: If the menu is open and the central widget is a QGLWidget, in my debugging, the tree widget cannot get the event. The event is just gone. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443854/requires-2-right-clicks-to-switch-context-menus-among-items